# pythonにて読み出した数値を特定の箇所に格納する方法

Tags: python

初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、解決いたしませんのでご教示頂けると幸いです。
下記で読み出した数値を特定の箇所に格納したいと考えております。
`device_names1`にて指定した６個のデータから、それぞれ`1,2,3,4,5,6`という結果が得られるとします。
その数値を例えば`A1_1,A1_2....`のような箇所に格納したいです。
この場合は配列が適切でしょうか？

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    device_names1 = ["CM700","CM701","CM702","CM703","CM704","CM705"]
    ip = '192.168.111.111'
    port = 1234

    for device_name in device_names1:
        A1 = dev(ip,port,device_name,1)
        print(device_name,A1)
```

追加での質問
回答頂きありがとうございます。 出力結果は上記の通りになりました。
不足している説明がございましたので、追記いたします。
TCP/IPで別の機種から情報を取得しており、そちらをA1_1、A1_2..のような場所に格納し、また別の箇所で引用したいと考えています。
取得された値 CM700:22、CM701:2、CM702:30等 ※取得される数値はランダムです。

```py
# 10進数16ビットで値をもらう
def recv_10deci16bit(ip, port, device_name, data_length):
    recv = ReceiveTruePLCValue(ip, port)
    recv_data = recv.receive_plc_data([device_name, data_length,
                                       '10decimal_16bit'])
    return recv_data

if __name__ =='__main__':
    # テスト的に利用
    device_names = ["CM700","CM701","CM702","CM703","CM704","CM705"]
    ip = '192.168.111.111'
    port = 1234
    for device_name in device_names:
        A1 = recv_10deci16bit(ip,port,device_name,1)
        print(A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

配列でもよいですが、[辞書型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)が適切ではないでしょうか。
下記のコードでは`dic_A`という配列を作成し、`A1_1`などのキーに対応する値として代入しています。

```
def dev(ip, port, device_name, i):
    return i + 1

if __name__ =='__main__':
    device_names1 = ["CM700","CM701","CM702","CM703","CM704","CM705"]
    ip = '192.168.111.111'
    port = 1234

    dic_A = {} # 辞書型の宣言
    for i, device_name in enumerate(device_names1):
        key = "A1_" + str(i + 1)
        value = dev(ip,port,device_name,i)
        dic_A[key] = value
        print(device_name, key, dic_A[key]) # 個別にキーと対応する値を取り出す
        
    print(dic_A)
```

出力結果

```
CM700 A1_1 1
CM701 A1_2 2
CM702 A1_3 3
CM703 A1_4 4
CM704 A1_5 5
CM705 A1_6 6
{'A1_1': 1, 'A1_2': 2, 'A1_3': 3, 'A1_4': 4, 'A1_5': 5, 'A1_6': 6}
```

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございました。
上記出力結果のとおり出力されました。
説明が不足している箇所がありましたので、本文更新いたしました。

Comment: 「別の箇所から引用」はA1_1などの値を別の関数から呼び出すという意味でしょうか？それとも別のpythonファイル実行時に呼び出すという意味でしょうか？辞書型では何が問題となりますか？疑問文に対するご説明をいただけますと、より良い回答を得やすいかもしれません。なお変数を別の箇所から利用する方法については類似質問がありますので、よろしければリンク先もご参照ください。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/83024/9820

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
A1_1などを別から読み出す方法になります。
頂いた辞書型の内容を当方のプログラムに置き換え検証してみましたが、
うまくいかなかったため、説明不足を含め再度情報を展開させて頂きました。
リンクも確認させて頂きます。